# Does yield return have any uses other than for IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, yield-return

Does C#'s `yield return` have a use outside of `IEnumerables`? For example, could it be used to implement coroutines without the use of multiple threads?

Comment: @JohnB Sorry, I wasn't looking for a way to implement coroutines. The idea of `yield return` just struck me as possibly lending itself towards coroutines, which is why I mentioned it. My real question was merely if `yield return` had any uses other than for `IEnumerable`s. Should I remove the coroutine part of the question?

Comment: First question: is it valid somewhere outside an IEnumerable method? I think not.

Comment: i see, i have submitted a change to your title to more effectively communicate that

Comment: You can google for C# and coroutines, several SO posts and libraries will show up. Add "-unity"

Comment: @HenkHolterman Isn't that the same question? If it is valid outside an `IEnumerable` method, then it has a use outside of `IEnumerable`s.

Comment: valid and useful aren't always the same. But since it is not valid the point is moot.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeah, you're right. If you turn that into an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question

> Does C#'s yield return have a use outside of IEnumerables

The answer is no, you can see this by the `yield` documentation

[yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> When you use the yield contextual keyword in a statement, you indicate
>   that the method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an
>   iterator. Using yield to define an iterator removes the need for an
>   explicit extra class (the class that holds the state for an
>   enumeration, see IEnumerator for an example) when you implement the
>   IEnumerable and IEnumerator pattern for a custom collection type.
>
> **Iterator methods and get accessors**
>
> The declaration of an iterator must meet the following requirements:
>
> **>>>The return type must be IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IEnumerator, or IEnumerator <<<**